# Regex match if src or href not starting with slash

Tags: php, regex

I try to match if **src** or **href** starts without slash e.g. `src="images/ajax.gif"`

I tried this:

```
src="^(?!/\*).*
```

But it does not match

Comment: How about `(src|href)="[a-zA-Z0-9].*"` ?

Comment: Or maybe `(src|href)="[^\/].*"` ?

Comment: Are you parsing HTML? Please consider using a HTML DOM parser, and you won't even need a regex.

Comment: No, I just need it for search & replace in notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `^`, anywhere else then ***start of pattern or first character in character class*** it doesn't have a special meaning, it will be treated as literal `^` only

```
src="(?!\/).*
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/JVwb1q/3/)

Comment: @yivi this is called regex visualizer, one such is this [`jex.im/regulex`](https://jex.im/regulex/)

Comment: I have a extra question, i don't want to make everyone mad if I ask yet another regex question on stackoverflow and get alot of downvotes... so what do I do? I am pretty sure that my regex is fine, but it does not work... 
https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=((%5Ehref%24%7C%5Esrc%24)%3D%5B%22%7C'%5D((%3F!%5C%2F)%7C(%3F!%23))).* should find all src or href not starting with slash or #, but it fails.

Comment: @Black you should not worry about down votes, but yes there must be minimum effort before posting a question, and you should includes those efforts in question as well, people here are happy to help if you show the effort. also whenever you write a question write in a bit details what you want where is it going wrong as per your thoughts along with input and desired outputs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `(src|href)="([^/]).*"`